# What is the SqlError.Number for "SHUTDOWN is in progress"?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a SqlException stack trace "from the wild" with the following message:

```
SHUTDOWN is in progress.
Login failed for user 'USERNAME'.
A severe error occurred on the current command.
The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

**Does anyone know what the [SqlError.Number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.number(v=vs.110).aspx) property is for this error?** I'm unable to reproduce the situation in order to determine it via debugging. In particular, I want to know the error code for "SHUTDOWN is in progress" but not for other cases of "A severe error..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645951(v=sql.105).aspx), it's 6005:

```
Error   Severity  Event Logged     Description
6005    10        No               SHUTDOWN is in progress.
```

You can also query the `sysmessages` table in the master database to find error numbers:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    master.dbo.sysmessages
WHERE
    description like '%shutdown is in progress%'
```

Which returns similar data as MSDN documents.